# PHP: Variable not incrementing

Tags: php

I was making a game of Rock, Paper, and Scissors with 10 rounds using HTML and PHP. The only problem that I encountered was `$player` , `$comp`, and `$round` doesn't increment and always goes to the initial value. What might be the problem?

This is my code for the PHP part:

```
<?php  session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['use'])) 
{
   header("Location:enter.php");  
}

if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['username']);
    header("location: enter.php");
}

$Computer='none';
$user_choice='';
$judgelose = array();
$judgewin = array();
$judgedraw = array();

$round=1;
$player=0;
$comp=0;

if(isset ($_POST['choice']))
{

    $Choosefrom= array('Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors');
    $Choice= rand(0,2);
    $Computer=$Choosefrom[$Choice];
    $user_choice=$_POST['choice'];

    if($user_choice == $Computer){
    array_push($judgedraw, 'Result : Draw');
    }
    else if($user_choice == 'Rock' && $Computer == 'Scissors' || $user_choice == 'Scissors' && $Computer == 'Paper' || $user_choice == 'Paper' && $Computer == 'Rock'){
    array_push($judgewin, 'Result : Win');
    $player++;
    }
    else if($user_choice == 'Rock' && $Computer == 'Paper' || $user_choice == 'Scissors' && $Computer == 'Rock' || $user_choice == 'Paper' && $Computer == 'Scissors'){
    array_push($judgelose, 'Result : Lose');
    $comp++;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to store those values in the session as well or else every time you load the page they will be reset.

Comment: Jon is right, you should just make your comment the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store those values in the session as well or else every time you load the page they will be reset. PHP won't remember values between page loads. That is what sessions are for. You should check if the value exists in the session and get it. If it doesn't exist, set an initial default value. Then many any changes you want to the variables and save them back into the session at the end. For example:

```
//check if the session for somevalue exists
if(isset($_SESSION['somevalue'])){
    //get it
    $somevalue = $_SESSION['somevalue'];
} else {
    //set a default value if not isset
    $somevalue = 0;
}

//do something with somevalue
$somevalue++;
//continue doing something with somevalue

//at bottom, save somevalue back into session.
$_SESSION['somevalue'] = $somevalue;
```